# Access specific controller in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code like:

`<my-directive ng-repeat="datum in data"></my-directive>`

Each instance of `my-directive` has a controller, which I would like to expose to the parent scope. Many guides say to inject the controller of `my-directive` into the parent scope, but won't calling a method on that have an effect on every instance of `my-directive` inside `ng-repeat`? I would like to have specific control over every instance of `my-directive`.

In the real-world application, the directive is a rather large module that deploys a video on the page from a range of vendors. Different vendors have different method names, like `play`, `playVideo`, etc. The directive abstracts these differences to a standard interface, as well as accepting init data, the id of the video to load, etc. I am looking for a way to call these standard interface methods from the parent controller. The example (with plunkr) below is a very simplified version of the control flow of the real thing.

The way I'm doing it now:

(my-directive.js)

```
link: ($scope, $element, $attr, $ctrl) {
    $scope.controller = $ctrl;
}
```

(my-page.html)

`<my-directive ng-repeat="datum in data" controller="datum.controller"></my-directive>`

(my-page-controller.js)

`data[someIndex].controller.doStuff()`

Is there any issue with doing it this way? Is there a better way?

**EDIT** http://plnkr.co/edit/BwI822V2NDTHPeIC8FMW

Comment: could you add plunkr please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this implementation.  You are passing the value from a model object to the directive as a string (using `@`), then backdooring your way into the directive to call a function which changes this directive's value, which leaves the directive further disconnected from the real value the data model holds.  what are you trying to gain by this?

Comment: for instance, if you hit that button multiple times, you are compound multiplying the value (3, then 6, then 12, then 24, etc...).  if the value at index 3 in the array changes, that's not reflected in the directive's value.  It's hard to see a use case where you need this kind of disconnected operation.

Comment: In the real-world application, the directive is a rather large module that deploys a video on the page from a range of vendors. Different vendors have different method names, like `play`, `playVideo`, etc. The directive abstracts these differences to a standard interface. I am looking for a way to call this `play` method on the directive.

Comment: well then that's your question, not this contrived XY example of a use case that isn't what you want anyway.....

Comment: You will have to forgive me. The real-world example is a bit big to fit into a plunkr. The example I posted has all the necessities I need for my question, including data passing and method calling. I will add the explanation to the main question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I would `$broadcast` a message with the index value, and when the directives controllers receives the message, the specific controller would know if the message was sent to it.

(my-page-controller.js)

```
$broadcast('doStuff', someIndex);
```

(my-directive.js)

```
$on('doStuff', function(index){
if (index == $scope.myDirectiveIndex)
  doStuff();
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's definitely one way of doing it, though it  seems a bit roundabout.

Comment: One downside is that if `<my-directive>` is used both with an `ng-repeat` as well as without it elsewhere on the page (as is the case with me), the `index` value is lost. You would have to add progressively more tracking values to the broadcast to make sure it reaches the right directive.

Comment: hmm, I understand now. I thought your parent controller would always have the indexes. I don't think your way of doing it is bad, but also I dont see another way of doing it...